# convert h5 file to csv file or text file for data processing

Tags: csv, hadoop, hdf5

i have a dataset of about 1.85 GB which contains h5 files,i need to process these files using hadoop,for this i may need to convert these files to text or csv.
 is there any way hadoop can read h5 files?or any good online tool to convert h5 files to csv or text files?or can any one give a link where i can download a huge dataset which contains text or csv files?

thanks in advance

Comment: h5dump (http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/Tools.html#Tools-Dump) will dump an HDF5 file to ASCII or XML, but the output will still be hierarchical not tabular like a CSV file.  Yes, there is some work going on to integrate HDF5 and Hadoop, use your favourite search engine to find it.

Comment: did you try R/MATLAB or C/C++ to read the content? R and MATLAB offers csv export; with C/C++ you are to use fprintf/cout.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried OPeNDAP Hyrax server with hdf5_handler module?

For example, from the sample HDF5 file [1], you can get the following ASCII data [2]:

```
Dataset: grid_1_2d.h5
temperature[0], 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10
temperature[1], 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11
temperature[2], 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12
temperature[3], 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13
...
```

OPeNDAP Hyrax server with hdf5_handler is a great tool/service because you can select (and subset) a dataset from an HDF5 file easily using HTML form as well [3]. You can find the detailed information about OPeNDAP hdf5_handler from [4].

[1] http://eosdap.hdfgroup.org:8080/opendap/data/hdf5/grid_1_2d.h5

[2] http://eosdap.hdfgroup.org:8080/opendap/data/hdf5/grid_1_2d.h5.ascii

[3] http://eosdap.hdfgroup.org:8080/opendap/data/hdf5/grid_1_2d.h5.html

[4] http://hdfeos.org/software/hdf5_handler.php